# Как посмотреть структуру .obj файла (объектного файла)

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер

Как посмотреть структуру .obj файла (объектного файла). Файла который подается на вход компоновщику. Создается visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Студия выдает файлы в COFF-формате. По крайней мере, 2013-я точно так делает. Спецификация на формат легко ищется, например в википедии. IDA умеет открывать этот формат и показывает код.

Comment: есть программа которая разбивает на поля этот файл?

Comment: В общем, эта программа довольно быстро и просто пишется, если вам не хватит того что в следующем ответе посоветовали.

Answer (score 0):

- Для разбора заголовка и простого дизассемблирования файлов PE и COFF форматов можно использовать консольную утилиту **dumpbin**, входящую в поставку Microsoft Visual Studio. Ключи командной строки: [Параметры DUMPBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/756as972.aspx)
- Также можно использовать утилиту **objdump**, входящую в пакет GNU Binutils. Также может показывать как общую информацию об объектном/исполняемом файле, так и дизассемблерный листинг. Поддерживает в том числе и файлы форматов PE и COFF. При желании можно нагуглить бинарные сборки под Windows.  Общая информация и ключи командной строки: [man objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump).
- Третий вариант: **rabin2** из пакета **radare2**, показывает информацию о бинарных файлах (заголовки, секции, импорты и т.д.) Общая информация: [Rabin2 — Show Properties of a Binary](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/tools/rabin2/intro.html) (Radare2 Book). Скачать пакет утилит целиком под нужную систему можно здесь: [Radare2 Downloads](http://radare.org/r/down.html)